# What does the value -9 means for fetch_status in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the fetch_status for each cursor in a nested loop. I am unable to use `@@FETCH_STATUS` here because of the nested loops (loop within another loop)

My first approach is to use `[sys.dm_exec_cursors][1]` to determine the status of each cursor by a name. Then if the fetch_status is not equal to 0 I would break the loop.

According to the [doc the fetch_status](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226062%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) should return one of the following values 0, -1, -2

However, the fetch_status in my case is returning `-9`. What does -9 means?

Here is how I try to get the status of the cursor based on the name

```
SET @fetchStatus =  (SELECT TOP 1 [fetch_status] FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (@@SPID | 0 ) WHERE name = 'pageCursor');
```

Here is a short version of my stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CloneSurvey] @sourceSurveyId INT, @newSurveyName VARCHAR(255)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @fetchStatus INT;

    If CURSOR_STATUS('global','pageCursor') <> -3
        DEALLOCATE pageCursor;


    DECLARE pageCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
     [id]
    FROM [survey_pages]
    WHERE survey_id = @sourceSurveyId;

    DECLARE @lastPageId INT;

    DECLARE @pageId INT;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRAN Survey;

        OPEN pageCursor;

        WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN

            SET @fetchStatus =  (SELECT TOP 1 [fetch_status] FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (@@SPID | 0 ) WHERE name = 'pageCursor');

            SELECT 'FETCH STAUS => ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fetchStatus);

            if @fetchStatus <> 0 AND @fetchStatus <> -9
                BREAK;

            FETCH NEXT FROM pageCursor 
            INTO 
              @pageId


            INSERT INTO surveys(page_id)
            SELECT @pageId;

            @lastPageId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            EXEC [dbo].[CloneQuestion] @lastPageId

        END;

        CLOSE pageCursor;
        DEALLOCATE pageCursor;

        COMMIT TRAN Survey;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
            ROLLBACK TRAN Survey;

    END CATCH;


END
```

Comment: Dunno, but [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190346.aspx) say it's the "the last returned `@@FETCH_STATUS` value". Off-hand, I'm wondering if -9 means that `@@FETCH_STATUS` was never accessed or if a fetch never occurred. That said, a fully reproducible example would probably go a *long* way toward figuring it out.

Comment: @jpmc26 you may be onto something here. I updated my question with a short version of my SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190346.aspx), the `fetch_status` column stores the last returned `@@FETCH_STATUS`. This implies that `fetch_status` is `undefined` before the first `FETCH` is executed against the cursor and it seems -9 is used to encode this. The example below does indeed show (SQL Server 2012) that the value is -9 before the first `FETCH` is called:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
    SELECT  1

OPEN cur1

--fetch_status = -9
SELECT  fetch_status
FROM       sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID)
WHERE   name = 'cur1'

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1;

--fetch_status=0
SELECT  fetch_status
FROM       sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID)
WHERE   name = 'cur1'
```

Comment: Indeed that was the correct answer. I wish the docs shows that and it only seems to explain 0, -1, -2